# How to create a web app for android?

Tags: android, web

I found out most websites give access to their sites via android apps. They allow to read posts and comment and play videos. I tries to use WebView but it wasn't pretty.

For example in our local newspaper use following app.

http://www.appbrain.com/app/lankadeepa/com.wijeya.lankadeepa

How they did that? I bought two android books and I know basic but when it comes to create an app, I am struck. I searched google but did not find how they create such an app.

Comment: You could also read the content of a website with httpget and then build it up in however way you see fit with android tools. Edit: This is hard work compared to using webview an simply wrap a mobile website.